# Passing data from JS to PHP is not working

Tags: php

I have an autocomplete googleapis that gets, latitude, longitude and adress correctly. When I try to pass these values to PHP, my ignorance of Java is making me do something wrong because php is not receiving any data.

JS

```
 <h1>Autocomplete form</h1>
 <input id="searchMapInput" class="mapControls" type="text" placeholder="- Type your location here -">
 <ul id="geoData">
 <li>Full Address: <span id="location-snap"></span></li>
 <li>Latitude: <span id="lat-span"></span></li>
 <li>Longitude: <span id="lon-span"></span></li>
 </ul>

 <script>
 function initMap() {
 var input = document.getElementById('searchMapInput');

 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    document.getElementById('location-snap').innerHTML = place.formatted_address;
    document.getElementById('lat-span').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('lon-span').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();

   function redirectToPosition(position) { 
   window.location='a.php?lat='+place.geometry.location.lat+'&long='+place.geometry.location.lng;
   }      
   });
   }
   </script>

   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY_goes here]&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer>
   </script>
```

And the serverside PHP is this (edited after comments)

```
<?php
$latitude = (isset($_GET['lat']))?$_GET['lat']:'';
$longitude = (isset($_GET['long']))?$_GET['long']:'';
echo "Latitude:".$latitude."</br>";
echo "Longitude:".$longitude;
?>
```

I get the url 
---/a.php?lat=function%20(){return%20a}&long=function%20(){return%20b}

and the following echos:

Latitude: function (){return a}

Longitude: function (){return b}

Comment: Your query string uses `lat` and `long`, you're checking for `lat-span` and `lon-span` in your PHP.

Comment: Your variables you are passing is lat and long and you are trying to get lat-span and lon-span

Comment: @ aynber Thank you so much for your help.  I replaced lat-span and long-span for lat and long in my PHP but my a.php is stil empty with no lat and lat echoing. Is the problem in JS functioinredirect?

Comment: @blupointmedia Thank you so much for your help. I replaced lat-span and long-span for lat and long in my PHP but my a.php is stil empty with no lat and lat echoing. Is the problem in JS functioinredirect?

Comment: Well, look at the URL that it redirect to when it redirects. Is the parameters empty in the URL?

Comment: @blupointmedia I get url  ---/a.php?lat=function%20(){return%20a}&long=function%20(){return%20b} and  I get Latitude:function (){return a}   longitude:function (){return b}

Comment: That means 'place.geometry.location.lat' and 'place.geometry.location.lng' are methods and not actual values. I would recommend doing a console.log of both of these, inside of this method (function redirectToPosition), comment out the redirection for testing, to see what the values are they hold.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `$_GET['lat']` and `$_GET['long']`

```
<?php
$latitude = (isset($_GET['lat']))?$_GET['lat']:'';
$longitude = (isset($_GET['long']))?$_GET['long']:'';
echo "Latitude:".$latitude."</br>";
echo "longitude:".$longitude;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In my php file (a.php) I have exactly what you sugested, but i get no result in echo $latitude or echo $longitude, so I think the problem is in the JS part. Couls you please give me a little help on that?